# Symfony2 - get form elements labels and types in controller/service

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Having form in `Symfony2 2.3.13`, while iterating through elements, for example this way:

```
$children = $form->all();

foreach($children as $name => $child){
    $child; // ->getLabel() ?
}
```

there is no `getLabel()` method, nor `getType()`, which I also need. while doing:

```
echo get_class($child);
```

I always get

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Form
```

Is there any way to get labels and types?

**Update**

I've tried to do how @Thomas Kelley proposed:

```
    $children = $form->all();
    foreach($children as $name => $child){
        echo '<pre>'; 
        var_dump($child->getType());
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Above code results in:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::getType()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$form->all()` returns an array of [`FormInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html).

You can access the configuration for that `FormInterface` via the `getConfig()` method, which returns a [`FormConfigInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/Form/FormConfigInterface.html). From there, you'll have access to both the type and the label:

```
$children = $form->all();
foreach ($children as $child) {

    /** @var FormInterface $child */

    /** @var FormConfigInterface $config */
    $config = $child->getConfig();

    /** @var ResolvedFormTypeInterface */
    $type = $config->getType();

    /** @var string $label */
    $label = $config->getOption("label");
}
```

(Note that `getType()` returns a [`ResolvedFormTypeInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/Form/ResolvedFormTypeInterface.html))

Comment: Ah! I said the words, but my code didn't follow them. I've updated it to actually _use_ the `getConfig()` that I talked about :P

Comment: Thanks! Gonna check this out tommorow :)

Comment: Thomas thank you again for your help. I created a bundle which anyone can use. https://github.com/Ex3v/FormErrorsBundle